# Interpretation of a term in Lambda Calculus

Tags: logic, formal-languages, lambda-calculus

Just started studying $λ$-calculus and I came across this $λ$-term : $$λx.λy.xy$$
As far as I understand this can be read as :

1. Apply $x$ to $y$
2. The result of $(1)$ is *probably* an expression say $E_1$
3. $y$ variable is a bound variable while $x$ is a free variable *in the context* of $E_1$
4. For some input $I$ apply $E_1$ to $I$ and the result is an expression say $E_{2}$ that depends on $x$

Everything emphasized is a hypothesis. Still trying to understand this formal system of writing functions so any insight would be really helpful.

Comment: The parenthesis in it would be $\lambda x.(\lambda y.(xy))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, with  explicit full parenthesization, the term is $\lambda x. (\lambda y. (xy))$

Thus, the meaning of the term $\lambda x. \lambda y. xy$ is the following. It is a function of two arguments (this is the meaning of the initial $\lambda x.\lambda y$) that takes the first argument (represented by the parameter $x$) and apply it to the second argument (represented by the parameter $y$), since $xy$ is the application of $x$ to $y$.

Remember that, in the $\lambda$-calculus, everything is a function and so it is standard that the argument of a function is another function.

In general, a term of the form $\lambda x. N$ has to be seen as a function $x \mapsto N$, i.e. a function that associates $x$ to $N$ (which, in turn, is another function). Hence, a term of the form $\lambda x. \lambda y. M$ has to be seen as a function $x \mapsto (y \mapsto M)$, i.e. a function that associates $x$ to a function that associates $y$ to $M$. By [(de-)currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), this is equivalent to see $\lambda x. \lambda y. M$ as a function that associates a couple of arguments $(x,y)$ to $M$.

Comment: Is this example an *accurate* translation of what you stated? $F(x,y)=x+y$ where by *applying* $x$ to $y$ is the addition of  $x$ to $y$. I emphasize accurate as from what I've read  $λ$ - calculus is just a formal system of writing functions.

Comment: @RookieCookie - Sorry, I'm not sure to understand what you mean when you say "Is the example above an accurate translation of what you stated?". What is the example above? Anyway, your interpretation of $F(x,y) = x + y$ is not accurate. The function $F(x,y) = x + y$ can be represented in the $\lambda$-calculus formalism as $\lambda x.\lambda y. (+ x) y$, where $+$ stands for a $\lambda$-term representing addition. Note that arithmetical addition $ x + y$ is a infix notation for the function $\lambda x. \lambda y. +(x,y)$, which is equivalent to say $\lambda x.\lambda y. (+ x) y$ by currying.

Comment: My example was the function $F(x,y)=x+y$ .I know that it was not so accurate and I was trying to understand the intuition behind applying $x$ to $y$ but I think I get it now. One last question though how would one interpret the $λx.λy.y$ or $λx.λy.x$ term? In each case the function consists of 2 arguments but one of them is not around. $x$ argument is not around in  $λx.λy.y$ and $y$ is not around in $λx.λy.x$.By not around I mean even though they are plugged in they are not used.

Comment: @RookieCookie - The term $\lambda x. N$ when $x$ does not appear in $N$ represents a function that associates $x$ to a function that does not depend on $x$, i.e. it takes an argument $x$ and discard it without using it. Hence, the $\lambda$-term $\lambda x. \lambda y. y$ represents the function $x \mapsto \lambda y.y$: with every argument it associates  the function $y \mapsto y$, which is the identity function. Pay attention that  I'm not saying that $\lambda x. \lambda y. y$ is the identity function, but that it is the function that associates every argument to the identity function.